# Javascript: using "!!" in boolean context

Tags: javascript, typescript, truthiness

Is there any reason to use `!!someValue` (which is equivalent to `Boolean(someValue)`) in a **boolean** context? In other words, in situations like `if (someValue) ...`, does it make sense to write `if (!!someValue) ...`?

It hurts my eyes and I think it's redundant, but I want to verify that there aren't any edge cases that require it - because I came across a codebase where this seems to be the default way of checking for truthiness.

**Clarification:** yes, in the general case `!!someValue` will convert `someValue` to a boolean; I'm referring to contexts where the runtime will automatically convert `someValue` to `true` or `false`.

Comment: Sometimes it's useful outside of if statements, if you need a boolean.

Comment: Of course, but I was asking specifically about boolean context (where the runtime will force the value to boolean anyway).

Comment: I don't think it's useful in a condition, but if you explicitly need a boolean, it matters: `console.log(1 && 2, !!1 && !!2)`.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is the !! (not not) operator in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/784929/what-is-the-not-not-operator-in-javascript)

Comment: It's a way to ensure boolean instead of truthy/falsey, for example having a value may match truthey but isn't technically `true`, it's just good practice where you want to ensure you have true/false instead of truthey/falsey

Comment: Your own clarification answers the question =)). You don't need `!!` in boolean context as JS coerces types to boolean implicitly.

Comment: @Kosh I'm in the process of reviewing codebase that use these a lot, I want to verify before I add comments that suggest they remove it.

Comment: Kosh is correct, you can rest assured that won't be the case within conditions; To give you some peace of mind, check out the mdn docs: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Truthy

Comment: @noamtm, I love your responsible approach to review!

Comment: I can't think of any scenario where you need `!!` in boolean context. Tested a bunch of data types (including all JS primitives) and I got the same outcome every time.

Answer (score 4):

That's a helpful way of converting any data type into boolean; The exact synonym would be:

```js
Boolean(someValue)
```

Some prefer the 'double bang' as being more coincise, while others prefer the classic conversion with `Boolean(someValue)` for better readability.

So returning to your question, it's most likely redundant in conditions, but it can be handy when needing a conversion from any type to boolean.

Comment: Readability is in the eye of the beholder. One could find `!!` better. =))

Comment: Haha so true, quite my preference too, although I worked in the past with teams that made me switch to "increase readability"!

Answer (score 0):

You never need to use a double bang to convert a boolean value to boolean.

```
boolean === !!boolean
```

Answer (score 0):

Can't say I know why anyone would rely on directly checking booleans rather than on truthiness, but there is at least one scenario where truthiness is different than coercing with `!!`.

```js
console.log([] == false); // true
console.log(!![] == false); // false
if([]) { console.log(true); } // true
if([] == false) { console.log(true); } // true
if(!![] == false) { console.log(true); } else { console.log(false); } // false
```

Comment: Your exceptional scenario isn't so much about truthiness as it is about the hidden pitfalls of loose equality.  An empty array, being an object, is truthy - hence !![] evaluates to true.  But double-equal treats it (and a few other surprising things) as false.